# Git: I set up a local machine to remote workflow. Where's the files on the remote?

Tags: git

What I'm looking for in a nutshell is my code traveling from left to right via a push:

```
local machine  ->  bare remote repository  ->  full remote repository
```

Note: the bare repo is on the same machine as the full repo.  The full repo is also my live site on a shared host.

After doing all the requirements for this, I see absolutely no files created on my server in my full repository.  Does git even do this?  I'm new to git so maybe I've messed something up.  All that I've done is listed below.

---

Here's what I've done on my local machine while in a directory with exiting code:

```
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

While on the remote machine, here's what I did for the bare repo:

```
$ mkdir -p $HOME/www/example.git
$ cd $HOME/www/example.git
$ git --bare init
```

Back to the local machine, I did this:

```
$ git push exampleserver master
$ git remote add exampleserver ssh://exampleuser@example.com/~/www/example.git
$ git push exampleserver master
```

Back to the remote machine, to set up the full repo/live website, I did this:

```
$ mkdir -p $HOME/www/example.com
$ cd example.com
$ git init
$ git remote add bare $HOME/www/example.git
$ cd $HOME/www/example.git/hooks/
```

While in the hooks directory in the bare repo, I created an executable shell script called 'post-update' and it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $HOME/www/example.com
unset GIT_DIR
git pull bare master

exec git-update-server-info
```

Finally, when finished coding on my local machine, I do the following:

```
$ git push exampleserver master
```

This returns 'everything is up-to-date'.

Comment: I don't get the "bare remote" thing. Why do you need a "bare remote" on your local machine? Just push to the server and get rid of the middleman...

Comment: I think the `post-update` hook is only run if there was anything *actually* pushed. What happens if you push a change?

Comment: @vocaro: Never push to a *non-bare* repository, bad things ensue.

Comment: I'm not suggesting he do the initial push to an existing repository. I'm questioning why he's creating a bare remote on his local machine, if the goal is to push code to the server. He should create the bare remote on the server and push to that. i.e., "local machine -> remote repository" with nothing in the middle...

Comment: Add "echo Running !" in you hook to check if it run. As per "git help hook": "Both standard output and standard error output are forwarded to git send-pack on the other end, so you can simply echo messages for the user.". Check that you "chmod u+x"ed the hook. Check that you did setup the repository non-bare repo ~exampleuser/www/example.com (and not ~whatever/www/example.com).

Comment: @vocaro, correct me if I'm wrong but my local machine merely has the initialized repository and the bare repo is on the remote.  I thought the bare remote is something that we don't touch and it's useful to have if ever I want to have someone else on my project.

Comment: @GregHewgill, on my local machine I made a new file and did 'git  add filename' and then pushed it out via 'git push exampleserver master'.  There are still no files in full repo/live server directory.

Comment: You create a bare remote when you want to push something to it. There's no point in creating a bare remote "just in case". So I'm still confused... You're trying to push to a SINGLE remote repository, but you created TWO remote repositories...?

Comment: @ysdx, where can you find standard error output.  Tried to find it but this seems cryptic to me.  Yes, the hook is executable.  Also, where/what file should I check to see that the setup of the non-bare repo is correct?  Not trying to be thickheaded, just exact.

Comment: @vocaro, I see what you're saying. I was just under the impression that there should be a bare repo just laying around as one's repository but you're saying that since I am developing on my local machine, it is the repo so I should just push to the remote repo (my intended live site directory) and call it a day right?  Is that a common way things are done with git?

Comment: The standard output and error of the hook should be forwarded as output of your "git push".

Comment: @BrandonMinton: yes, exactly. I'm not sure how you got the impression that a "bare remote repository" needs to sit between your local repo and the one you're pushing to. Eliminating this complication might solve your problem, or at least simplify it enough to help you solve it.

Comment: @vocaro: I don't see anything wrong with the bare repo setup that the OP has. It's quite common, and good practice, to have a bare repository that you push your development work to, and pull your production work from. Please don't advocate eliminating the bare repository. One must *never* push directly to a repo that has a working directory.

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm not a web developer, but I'm not familiar with this practice. I keep my development and production work in separate branches ("develop"/"master"), not separate repositories. Is there a site somewhere that discusses this practice?

Comment: @vocaro, Daniel Miessler's site illustrates what I'm trying to do and explains how to do it.  Glad I found this: http://danielmiessler.com/study/git/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Now I see that you're trying to use Git as a site deployment mechanism. Basically you're copying your workspace to the web site, and using Git to do the copying. I think it'd be simpler (and you'd get more power and flexibility) by using a tool designed for that specific purpose, such as Maven's Deploy plugin or Ruby's Capistrano. For me, I only push a Git repo when I need to back it up or share it with other developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If push echoes 'everything is up-to-date' your hook will not have been called as there was nothing updated. As pointed out by @ysdx standard output is forwarded and you can use echo to output additional information.

So a push of an actual change would look like this:

```
Counting objects: 5, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 244 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: /git/server /git/remote
remote: From ../remote
remote:  * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
remote: Updating e10977b..21d83ca
remote: Fast-forward
remote:  test.txt |    2 +-
remote:  1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
remote: /git/remote
To ../remote
   e10977b..21d83ca  master -> master
```

You can see the output from the pull called from the hook there. In fact all the lines starting with 'remote:' are forwarded from the hook. Whereas if your hook was not invoked you would get an output like this:

```
Counting objects: 5, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 243 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
To ../remote
   21d83ca..aac857c  master -> master
```

Other then that its probably worth using pushd/popd for the directory change. I basically used the same script as you to generate the above output:

```
pushd ../server
unset GIT_DIR
git pull remote master
popd

exec git update-server-info
```

Comment: when I do a push from my local machine, I'm simply told that 'everything is up-to-date'.  Maybe I need to commit?

Comment: Also, I'm expecting git to copy new files and edited ones to my live server directory ($HOME/www/example.com) when I do a push from my local machine and maybe git doesn't do that but rather need to scp or something?

Comment: Every time you make changes you need to first 'git add' those changes, then 'git commit' them then 'git push' them to the server. Push is only aware of commits so you can (in general) only push what has been committed. Commit in turn is (in general) only aware of what is on the index. And to get changes from you working directory onto the index you use add.

Comment: Chris, I gave you the answer to this question for making a solid attempt.  I appreciate it.  I actually figured out how to accomplish what I want from Daniel Miessler's site posted in the comments above.  What worked was instead of using a post-update hook, using the post receive hook.  Given, I might have dummied something up with the post-update hook :/  Again, thank you for your guidance.